# Access `this` from within required object literal?

Tags: javascript, object

I desire to have the following type of object:

```
const Client = require('./Client')
let client = new Client()

client.someObject.create(...)
client.someObject.update(...)
client.someObject.delete(...)
etc.
```

This is very easy to accomplish doing something like this:

```
const Client = function () {
  this.someObject = {}
  this.someObject.create = function () {...}
  this.someObject.update = function () {...}
  this.someObject.delete = function () {...}
}
module.exports = Client
```

But from an organizational standpoint (and because of the massive number of functions `someObject` has, it would be helpful to put all the `someObject` stuff into it's own file and require it: `require('./someObject')`. However, I still need to be able to access the `Client` object (`this`) within `someObject.create()`, `someObject.update()`, etc.

```
this.someObject = require('./someObject')

// someObject.js
module.exports = {
  create: function () {
    // How do I access Client here? Can I pass it to the object literal?
  }
}
```

I've tried to do some prototype sub module type of setup but it doesn't appear to work.

`Client.prototype.someObject.create = function () { ... }`

How can I separate `someObject` into it's own file and still access the Client `this`?

Comment: It will probably require a circular reference. Perhaps `this.someObject = { client: this };`. Then, `create`, etc. can use `this.client`.

Comment: I don't understand: right now, when calling `client.someObject.create()`, the `this` equals `someObject` and not `client`.

Comment: @le_m Yes. Within someObject I would call it `client` or something. I just want a way to ACCESS it within someObject. Doesn't matter what it is called.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you. I considered this, but it would be nice to keep the `this.someObject` definition in the other file. Would it make a difference if it was a function instead of an object literal and I could just pass this into the function?

Comment: @JakeWilson I was referring to your "This is very easy to accomplish doing something like this" - example. How do you currently access the client's `this` within e.g. `create` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide the `Client` instance to `someObject` itself so the latter's methods can use it to reference the former.

One way you accomplish that is to define a 2nd constructor for `someObject` that takes the client as an argument.

```
const SomeObject = function (client) {
  if (!client) throw new Error('Client reference is required.');
  this.client = client;
};

SomeObject.prototype.create = function () {
  let client = this.client;
  // ...
};

// ....

module.exports = SomeObject;
```

```
const SomeObject = require('./someObject');

const Client = function () {
  this.someObject = new SomeObject(this);
}
```

---

You can also get a similar result with `Object.create()` if you'd rather keep the object literal:

```
const baseline = {
  create: function () {
    let client = this.client;
    // ...
  },

  // ...
};

module.exports = function createSomeObject(client) {
  return Object.create(baseline, {
    client: {
      value: client
    }
  });
};
```

```
const createSomeObject = require('./someObject');

const Client = function () {
  this.someObject = createSomeObject(this);
};
```

Comment: Ah man I was way overthinking this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I guess using an object literal was not necessary in this case. Thank you,

Comment: @JakeWilson Well, I added an alternative if you'd rather keep using the object literal.